# Swift Combine framework multiple async request responses into one

Tags: swift, zip, combine

Here is a pseudo code of what I need to achieve:

```
func apiRequest1() -> Future<ResultType1, Error> { ... }
func apiRequest2() -> Future<ResultType2, Error> { ... }
func transform(res1: ResultType1, res2: ResultType2) -> ResultType3 { ... }

func combinedApiRequests() -> Future<ResultType3, Error> {
    (resultType1, resultType2) = execute apiRequest1() and apiRequest2() asynchronously
    resultType3 = transform(resultType1, resultType2)
    return a Future publisher with resultType3
}
```

How would `combinedApiRequests()` look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to return a `Future` publisher. `Future` publisher is a specific publisher, but as far as a downstream is concerned, a publisher is defined by its output and failure types. Instead, return a `AnyPublisher<ResultType3, Error>`.

`Zip` is a publisher that waits for all results to arrive to emit a value. This is probably what you'd need (more on this later). This is how your function could look:

```
func combinedApiRequests() -> AnyPublisher<ResultType3, Error> {
   Publishers.Zip(apiRequest1, apiRequest2)
             .map { transform(res1: $0, res2: $1) }
             .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

---

There is also `CombineLatest` publisher. For the first result from each upstream, it behaves the same as `Zip`, but for subsequent results it differs. In your case, it doesn't matter since `Future` is a one-shot publisher, but if the upstream publishers emitted multiple values, then you'd have to decide for your specific use case whether to use `Zip` - which always waits for **all** upstreams to emit a value before it emits a combined value, or `CombineLatest` - which emits with each new upstream value and combines it with the latest for other upstreams.